# Adding start menu button programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I am looking for the proper way to programmatically add start button to Windows 8 taskbar using C# or C++. I have search for this problem in MSDN, but I couldn't find anything useful. Could you hint me something?

Comment: What exactly is a start button on the Windows 8 taskbar?

Comment: Microsoft removed a menu start button in Windows 8. I am looking for the way to add it again to taskbar, such as in previous versions of Windows. There are few programs, which can do it - e.g ClassicShell

Comment: IIRC its a reg key to enable the start button. this msdn link will tell you how to set a reg key (c#). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx

edit: that link is creating keys, this one coveres writing http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Comment: the key you need is 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer'

Change RPEnabled from 1 to 0

Comment: @Jay . Thank you. Your tip looks very simple. I am going to use it in Windows 8 Developer Preview, but I have doubts if it will work in Windows 8 RTM... I have heard, that Microsoft wanted to remove this hack from final version of Windows 8.

Comment: @Viper I don't have access to RTM unfortunately. Hope you get it sorted!